# React-native TextInput how to throttle onBlur function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my React Native project, I have the following piece of code:

```
<TextInput onBlur={(e) => this.handleBlurCheck(e, ...otherParams)}/>
```

I want to throttle the function `handleBlurCheck`, but in React Native, I don't know how to do that.

Also, I need the `event` parameter.

Comment: By throttle, do you mean that you want the event handler to only happen N times in a given time?

Comment: in a given time just trigger 1times

Comment: You can use lodash, it has a function called `debounce` that does exactly what you're after.

Comment: I know, but how to use it in here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a function in your component called `handleBlurCheck`, you can create a new function:

```
this.throttledHandleBlurCheck = _.throttle(this.handleBlurCheck, timeWindow)
```

Then, in your render code:

```
<TextInput onBlur={(e) => this.throttledHandleBlurCheck(e,...otherParams) }/>
```

Comment: create a new function ? like this:

throttledHandleBlurCheck(e,subTitle,identifier){
    this.throttledHandleBlurCheck = debounce(this.handleBlurCheck, this)
  }

no, it does't work

Comment: No, the form I wrote already creates the function. You can put that in the component constructor, for example.

Comment: but the function `throttledHandleBlurCheck` used for what? A empty function? I need pass params through `handleBlurCheck`;

And without lodash,can I realize it?

Comment: When you use `throttle`, it creates a function that wraps the given function. Any parameters you provide to the new function, will be passed to the original one.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer solves your question, please mark it as *accepted*. This will prevent other people trying to answer the same question.